# Disable (not hide) main scroll bar on mouseover of an element with javascript/css?

Tags: javascript, css

Required behaviour: on mouseover of an element I would like to disable main browser window scrolling or at least doing so with the mousewheel.  I want to keep the visibility of the scroll bars while they are disabled.

Reason: The page is approximately twice the height of the browser window.  There is a div with scroll bars.  When scrolling with the mouse on the div and the bottom or top of the list is hit the main window starts to scroll.  This is unwanted behaviour because often the main window scroll will either move the divs content on the screen or even scroll it off the screen completely which is very annoying.  I would like to be able to mouse scroll to the bottom of the div without the main window scroll taking over and then scrolling the div out of view.  The reason I would like any disabled scroll bars to stay visible is because if they are hidden the width of the page stretches to fit the gap making content jump/move which is unsightly and also problematic for mouseovers.

Is this possible using javascript/css but not jquery?

Comment: You are describing the default browser behavior.  It's what people come to expect and probably shouldn't be tinkered with.

Comment: I think I disagree at least in this specific example.  If a user had to click an element to make a long scrolling drop down menu visible (which is the case in my example) and is then moused over the menu and using the scroll wheel then it can safely be taken as a given that the user is focussing on that content and wants to scroll just it as opposed to a situation where someone might be mistakenly mousedover the element while trying to scroll the whole screen and failing.  I can't see that a user would be scrolling in this situation and would want the viewed content scrolled offscreen.

Comment: In this case I believe changing the default behaviour would be beneficial.

Comment: No need to give complicated examples... I too am annoyed by how browsers handle this.  However, I also expect my mouse-wheel to act the same no matter what site I happen to be visiting.

Comment: If the sites did what you wanted rather than the annoying expected behaviour you would be concerned?  Maybe pleasant surprise would over-ride your sense of concerned unfamiliarity.

Comment: And if half of sites implemented what you propose... I would be twice as annoyed when how my mouse-wheel performs becomes a crap-shoot.  That is my last comment.

Answer (score 0):

using jquery you can let the page sroll to the last position you had when the mouse entered
the other scrolling zone:

```
    var scrolltop = 0;
    var handler = function(ev){$(window).scrollTop(scrolltop)};

    $(element).bind("mouseover", function(ev){ 
        scrolltop = $(window).scrollTop();
        $(window).bind("scroll",handler);
    });

    $(element).bind("mouseout", function(ev){ 
        $(window).unbind("scroll",handler);
    });
```

where element is the other scrolling zone